# Comand button 1 and 2 have swapped over?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code for two command buttons. It worked fine while I was writing and testing the code. However as I've gone to the sheet today and tested the buttons they have swapped over. I've renamed the buttons and that didn't work and I've even swapped the names over and it still runs the code of its counterpart.

```
'Show new entry form
Private Sub CommandButtonNew_Click()
NewCollectionUserForm.Show
End Sub

'Email range
Private Sub CommandButtonEmail_Click()

Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Uplifts"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "Hi, Here is the the current outstanding uplifts:"
    .Item.To = "test@test.com"
    .Item.CC = "test2@test.com"
    .Item.Subject = "Outstanding Uplifts"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Item.Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you rename the `Sub`s as well?

Comment: Yes I've renamed the Subs as well but did work. Could this be a bug with VBA?

Answer (score -1):

right click on your button , go to Assign Macro, and assign the correct one maybe?
The name in the list of macros will be the name of the sub (i.e CommandButtonNew_Click())

Comment: OP's buttons are `Active-X controls`, not `Form controls`.  Your method will only work on `Form controls`.